# Was conversing or conversed

Tags: grammaticality

Should it be:

1: As I was conversing with him about his love for jazz, I measured the temperature and found it to be 100 degrees.

2: As I conversed with him about his love for jazz, I measured the temperature and found it to be 100 degrees.

Is there any better ways to break this up?

Comment: Both are fine. What exactly do you want broken up?

Comment: I believe he's referring specifically to "As I was conversing" vs. "As I conversed".

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, their differences are in [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect), which describes how a verb relates to time. It's not the same thing as tense. The first uses the past tense [progressive aspect](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/progtenseterm.htm) verb phrase "was conversing", and the second uses the past tense verb without an aspect "conversed". Progressive aspect is used to show things that are still happening: e.g. the present tense progressive "I am conversing" suggests I'm still conversing now. It always contains a form of the modal auxiliary "to be". It's a little harder to explain how past tense progressive works: "I was conversing" suggests that I was conversing continuously up until a point, and then I stopped. The progressive aspect is different from the [perfect aspect](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/perfect_aspect.htm), which uses the modal auxiliary "to have", and expresses an action that is completed, e.g. "I have conversed" is in present tense perfect aspect, and suggests that you finished conversing recently. "I had conversed" is the past tense perfect aspect, suggesting that you had finished conversing at some time in the past.

If a verb phrase doesn't have an aspect, as in your second example, that means it has neither the modal auxiliary "to be" (which is used for progressive aspect) nor "to have" (which is used for perfect aspect) before the main verb: it just uses the verb on its own. If you had to stick an auxiliary in there, you would use "do". So "I converse" and "I do converse" are essentially the same, as are "I conversed" and "I did converse". All four examples don't have an aspect.

As for which of the two is better, I think the first sounds a little stilted to me, I would personally prefer the second one, but both are grammatically valid, and you can use either.